# How StackWalk64 behaves with inline functions?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, callstack

I am trying to capture the call-stack using the dbghelp.dll functions. I am using StackWalk64 to capture the addresses of the functions in the call-stack.The behavior of StackWalk64 with inline functions looks undeterministic for me. Sometimes, it skips the inline functions. Some other times I can get an address back for them but stackwalk64 fails for the next function in the call stack. In both cases I get incomplete call-stacks.

Anyone has more insights into that and on how to handle inline functions in call-stacks.

Thanks

Comment: How are you determining the functions you think are inline are indeed inline? `inline` won't do it. You have the same problem viewing a callstack in the debugger with functions that actually get inlined. Run without optimizations to see a more reliable callstack.

Comment: So, you are correct. I double checked the behavior. StackWalk64 will skip the inline functions always which is logical. I thought I was using the debug builds but I figured out later that I was using the optimized builds. Thanks for the answer :)